# Crop path outside text region in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text, svg, path

I have a text (created with the **Text** tool), with `fill: none` and `stroke: black 3px`.
Also, I imported an SVG image (using *File > Import*), which I wanted to put as text background.

[image: The image I'm talking about]

**What I tried:**

- *Object > Clip > Set*, with both text in front and path in front.
- *Object > Pattern > Objects to Pattern* with the path, but can't position the pattern exactly as I want it to be by using the *Node* tool.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Bryan! Have you tried to create a duplicate (Ctrl+D) of the text and place it over the brown clipped path?

Comment: Thanks! After doing that I still need to move the text 2 pixels to the left but it does what I wanted. Could you post your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create a duplicate (Ctrl+D) of the text and place it over the brown clipped path.
>   By [@Paolo Gibellini](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80665/crop-path-outside-text-region-in-inkscape?noredirect=1#comment123726_80665)

That did the job after placing both elements in same position and moving "words" 1px left.